# Gitlab installation dos't respond on centos 7

Tags: gitlab, centos7, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ee

I uninstall "Gitlab-ee Omnibus" from centos 7 with following commands :

```
sudo yum -y remove gitlab-ee
sudo rm -rf /opt/gitlab/
sudo rm -rf /var/opt/gitlab
sudo rm -rf /var/log/gitlab
sudo rm -rf /etc/gitlab
```

Then reboot the system and try to re-install it as demonstrate [in this doc.](https://about.gitlab.com/install/#centos-7)

But after some hours this installation doesn't respond. The installation process is :

```
Total download size: 763 M
Installed size: 1.7 G
Downloading packages:
gitlab-ee-12.6.0-ee.0.el7.x86_64.rpm                       | 763 MB   01:00
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : gitlab-ee-12.6.0-ee.0.el7.x86_64            1/1
```

I also try to run `gitlab-ctl status` command but it returns :

```
warning: redis: unable to open supervise/ok: file does not exist
```

What should I do? Can I cancel its installation process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold down `CTRL+C` Force the installation to end and run the following command:

```
sudo systemctl restart gitlab-runsvdir
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

In this way, the command execution is usually successful. This command can solve almost everyone's problems.
In addition, you can directly [GitLab Common installation problems](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/common_installation_problems/README.md#common-installation-problems) Find the answer to this question.